# Query formula not working with error AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

I am getting this error on my query.

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC

I don't understand whats the problem is here. actually, I have 2 columns in my data sheet with "W" is Gross Sale "Z" is the Net sale
My query is perfectly working with column "W" which is a Currency cell, and numbers are manually entered for each row while not working with column "Z" which is a calculated cell with the below formula

> IF(ISBLANK(W2)," ",SUM(W2-X2)-Y2) I am also unable to make this formula as an array formula (might need help here too)

[image: Not working query]
[image: The data]

PS: I can share the sheet if anyone want to help directly on the sheet.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hello, I have somewhat achieved what i wanted by apply array formula to column Z, now my query doing what it should do. but issue in now in column Z. column Z showing $0.00 where Calculated Column are empty.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18q6UHPjJjcCsUkLC6mPBmeltQOxZwnex9OPuA44_EcU/edit?usp=sharing
here is the link. waiting for your input

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18q6UHPjJjcCsUkLC6mPBmeltQOxZwnex9OPuA44_EcU/edit?usp=sharing here it is

Comment: Since what you are describing looks to be another issue, please post a new question in this case. @AliAhmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!D1:D5000, Sheet1!W1:W5000, 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!Z1:Z5000, "\d+.\d+|\d+"))*1}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3),count(Col3)
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col1 
  order by Col1 desc
  label sum(Col3)'Gross Sale', count(Col3)'Total Orders'"))
```

Comment: Why does this solution work? Query language is not at all intuitive for me.

Comment: @Veggiet QUERY likes to "assume" the type of dataset (numeric or plain text) and swing in favor of majority. this means query is sensitive on formatting (if number is formated as numeric or text - like in this case). aggregation (sum,average,max,min,count) in query works only with numeric numbers/values therefore in this case we needed to extract numbers from text formatted cells either in `#.#` or `#` pattern and convert it to numeric by multiplication of 1

Comment: another hacky workaround that worked for me is to put a single 0 in that column on the very last row.  I believe this allows the sheet to recognize the column as numeric, even though in my case, there were no values in that column